# bluetooth stops working after resuming from sleep

Tags: wireless, 15.04, suspend, bluetooth

I am on Lenovo Z50-70 running Ubuntu 15.04 with Linux kernel 4.0

My bluetooth works fine until I resume from sleep, it says *bluetooth is disabled*, it doesn't start even if i toggle the OFF button (see image below)

output of `lsusb; lsmod | grep bluetooth; dmesg | grep firmware` is:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 5986:055e Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
bluetooth             446409  12 bnep,ath3k,btusb,rfcomm
[  483.670589] usb 1-7: device firmware changed
```

[image]

Comment: There is nothing to suggest, but to report a bug. Also you can fix it by patching `btusb.c`. It looks like the module loses firmware on sleep. If you post a ling to the bug report, I will look into it.

Comment: You can also try to do `sudo modprobe -r ath3k && sleep 2 && sudo modprobe ath3k` to load firmware.

Comment: @Pilot6 i tried running above set of commands but it didnt help

Comment: @Pilot6 can you pls tell me how to patch btusb ?

Comment: I can't tell you how to patch kernel for two reasons. 1. I do not know what the exact patch must be yet. It needs some research and testing. 2. If you never patched and built kernel modules, I can't explain it in one sentence. If you report this bug, I will try to fix it and will build a module for you to test it.

Comment: @Pilot6 i am found 3 different solution on [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1242310) page, i will be trying them one by one and will report here in answer

Comment: This is an old bug report regarding other devices. Why don't you create your own bug report and let me or others fix this problem for everyone instead of trying all relevant and irrelevant commands and solutions? Do you know how to create a bug report at launchpad?

Comment: @Pilot6 no, tell me how to report a bug, also i cant find the launch bug report link on launchpad

Comment: Run in terminal `ubuntu-bug linux`, browser will open. Just follow directions. When report is created post a link to it for me. Or subscribe me.